# Ошибка curl_setopt() , что не так?

Tags: php, curl

Подклчюаюсь к api, данные обратно получа , но с ошибкой: 
curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myurl.com/get/data');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'API_KEY: '.$api_opts,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
        ));

        $err = curl_errno($ch); 

        $result = json_encode(curl_exec($ch));

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
```

В чем прична?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ошибке как раз и указано в чем проблема - curl_setopt должна получить три аргумента, а в строке

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING);
```

их только два. Нужно передать третий параметр - кодировку, например

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php